# copy files from mount point listed in a csv

Tags: bash, loops, unix, awk, copy

I need to move over 100,000 img's from 1 server to another via a mount point, i have a .csv with them listed  and im looking to script it
the csv looks like this

```
"images1\002_0001\thumb",53717902.jpg,/www/images/002_0001/thumb/
"images1\002_0001\thumb",53717901.jpg,/www/images/002_0001/thumb/
"images1\002_0001\thumb",53717900.jpg,/www/images/002_0001/thumb/
```

comma separated we have source name and destination

I was thinking of using awk to create each as a variable

```
SOURCE=`awk -F ',' '{ print $1 }' test.csv`
IMGNAME=`awk -F ',' '{ print $2 }' test.csv`
DEST=`awk -F ',' '{ print $3 }' test.csv`
```

this is where im getting stuck, my loop

```
while read line
do
    cp $SOURCE${IMGNAME} $DEST
done <test.csv
```

this has copied the first name it finds into all the directories

Comment: Please tell us if it functions...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many way to do it, some example

1. If you have no spaces in the directories string: you can do even from shell
   `sed -E 's/"/cp /; s/",/\// ; s/,/ /;s/\\/\//g' test.csv | /bin/bash`
   It better if **check it before you try**. You speak about a lot of files...
   `sed -E 's/"/cp /; s/",/\// ; s/,/ /;s/\\/\//g' test.csv | less`
2. It can happen that you have **spaces in** the string of the **directory name** like `My Windows Like Dir Name`. In this case you need double quotes (there are the double quote even for this reason maybe...)
   You can do it using only `awk`(always from the shell)
   `awk -F',' '{gsub(/"/, "", $1); gsub(/\\/, "/", $1); print "cp \""$1"/" $2"\" \"" $3"\""}' test.csv  | /bin/bash`
   or that is equivalent
   `awk -F',' '{gsub(/"/, "", $1); gsub(/\\/, "/", $1); printf ("cp \"%s/%s\" \"%s\"\n",$1,$2,$3)}' test.csv | /bin/bash`
   Check it always in advance, avoiding the last pipe `|/bin/bash`, putting maybe `| head -n 10` to have only the first 10 lines.

The script can be written:

```
  while IFS=, read -r SOURCE IMGNAME DEST
  do
   SOURCE=( ${SOURCE//\\/\/} )         # Here you need to change "\" in "/"
   SOURCE=( ${SOURCE//\"/} )           # Here I like to kill ""
   cp  "${SOURCE}/${IMGNAME}" "$DEST"  # Here I put again ""
  done <test.csv
```

Note: I think you need to change "\" windows style in "/" unix style. So I required to the substitution rules.

Comment: excellent, this works fine with a smaller file, but run it on the 4 mil line csv i have and i run out of memory, is there anything more effecient?

Comment: Did you run out of memory even with the command line commands? I updated the answer to use only one command or `sed` (without `""`) or `awk` (with `""`). If you finish memory even so, try to `split` the file in more files and after execute them one after the other. (In general you can redirect the output of the command to a text file `>NewCommandFile` instead of `| /bash/bin`. After you can split that file and do a little script that execute them one after the other... _Dividi et Impera!_ ).

Answer (score 1):

You could use what you have and move the variable declaration into the loop referencing $line, or you could use IFS, as suggested below.

```
   while IFS=, read -r src filename dest
   do
      cp $src${filename} $dest
   done <test.csv
```

Comment: this fixed the memory issue

Comment: while read LINE
do
 SOURCE=$(echo $LINE | awk -F ',' '{ print $1 }')
 DEST=$(echo $LINE | awk -F ',' '{ print $2 }')
 cp $SOURCE  $DEST